# Problem printing the content of a waiting queue in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, process, character-device

**Context:** Consider the following set of operations {A, B, C, D, E}:

- (A) : On the `read()` function of my device driver, I add the calling thread to a wait queue `wq` if a driver's buffer `buf` is empty.

More specifically, the calling thread is added to the queue via:

```
wait_event_interruptible(wq, strlen(buf) > 0)
```

- (B) : Similarly, on the `ioctl()` function of the driver, I add the calling thread to the same queue `wq` if the passed `ioctl` command is `MY_IOCTL_X` and if a driver's flag `is_free == 0`.

Again, the calling thread is added to the waiting queue via:

```
wait_event_interruptible(wq, is_free != 0)
```

- (C) : On the driver's `write()` function, I pass the user-space content to `buff`, and call `wake_up_interruptible(&wq)`, so that to wake up the thread put to 'sleep' in `read()`.
- (D) : On the driver's `ioctl()` function,  if the `ioctl` command is `MY_IOCTL_Y`, I set `is_free = 1`, and call `wake_up_interruptible(&wq)`, in order to wake up the thread put to 'sleep' by `ioctl(MY_IOCTL_X)`.
- (E) : I've created a `print_wait_queue()` function to print the PIDs of the threads in the waiting queue. I call it before **and after** calling `wake_up_interruptible()` in operations C and D.

The print function is implemented like this:

```
void print_wait_queue(struct wait_queue_head* wq)
{
  struct list_head *i, *tmp;
  pr_info("waiting queue: [");
  list_for_each_safe(i, tmp, &(wq->head)) 
  {
    struct wait_queue_entry* wq_item = list_entry(i, struct wait_queue_entry, entry);
    struct task_struct* task = (struct task_struct*) wq_item->private;
    pr_info("%d,", task->pid);
  }
  pr_info("]\n");
}
```

**Problem:** The actual queueing and de-queueing seems to be working as intended, no issues here.

However, the printing of the wait queue is not.

Let's say I perform the operations described above, in this order: A -> B -> C -> D.

This is what I get in the console (simplified output):

1. “waiting queue : [pid_1, pid_2]” // before calling `wake_up_interruptible()` on `write()`
2. “waiting queue : []” // after calling `wake_up_interruptible()` on `write()` (**I was expecting [pid_2]**)
3. “waiting queue : [pid_2]” // before calling `wake_up_interruptible()` on `ioctl(MY_IOCTL_Y)`
4. “waiting queue : []” // after calling `wake_up_interruptible()` on `ioctl(MY_IOCTL_Y)`

As shown above, at print #2, the PID of the remaining thread - pid_2 - doesn’t show up in the PID list. Instead, I get an empty list.

However, pid_2 shows up in the list before calling `wake_up_interruptible()` on `ioctl(MY_IOCTL_Y)` at print #3, as expected, indicating that `pid_2` is actually kept in the waiting queue in-between prints #2 and #3.

**Questions:** Why don’t I get [pid_2] at print #2 above, but then get it at #3?

I’ve tried protecting the wait queue cycle in `print_wait_queue()` with a lock and it didn’t solve the printing issue.

I've also confirmed that the address that the pointer I pass to `print_wait_queue()` always points to the same address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My observations are expected behaviour.

As mentioned [here](https://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2.shtml), in section 6.2.2 :

> `wake_up()` wakes up **all processes waiting on the given queue** (...). The other form (`wake_up_interruptible()`) restricts itself to processes performing an interruptible sleep.

As such, at print #2 above, immediately after calling `wake_up_interruptible()`, the state of both tasks is `runnable`, and as such, both tasks are removed from the wait queue. However, the `ioctl()` task is about to go to sleep again, since it's condition isn't verified yet.

I've confirmed this by looking at the task state of pid_2 on `gdb` before and after each `wake_up_interruptible()`:

- At print #2, the `ioctl()` task was in fact in state 0, i.e. `runnable` [[1]](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/include_2linux_2sched_8h_source.html#l01191).
- At any point after print #2 and before print #3, the task was in state 1, i.e. `stopped` [[1]](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/include_2linux_2sched_8h_source.html#l01191).